# Concatenate a column based on the other columns being the same

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a number of rows where 5 of the columns are the same and the 6th isn't.

I want to be able to group the 5 columns and the concatenate row values of the 6th column into one

I've tried using CTE and STUFF but I can't seem to get it to do what I need. I've also seen lost of example of how to rollup columns into one row but most examples just deal with 2 columns (e.g. User and course)

I'm using SQL server 2016(130) so I can't use STRING_AGG

Query [SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/263a33/1)

This is my data from the query below

| sitename | pageTitle | pageurl | dateCreated | expiryDate | reviewer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xSite | sql concat | //abc.com/fr | 02/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 | James (jk jk@something.com) |
| xSite | sql concat | //abc.com/fr | 02/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 | David (dDel jk@something.com) |
| xSite | sql concat | //abc.com/fr | 02/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 | Ali (aLee aLee@something.com) |
| xSite | Join in SQL | //abc.com/vf | 18/02/2020 | 2/05/2022 | Ken (kK kk@something.com) |
| ySite | Just SQL | //abc.com/a | 31/01/2022 | 21/05/2023 |  |

This is what I would like to return

| sitename | pageTitle | pageurl | dateCreated | expiryDate | reviewer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xSite | sql concat | //abc.com/fr | 02/02/2023 | 28/02/2023 | James (jk jk@something.com), David (dDel jk@something.com), Ali (aLee aLee@something.com) |
| xSite | Join in SQL | //abc.com/vf | 18/02/2020 | 2/05/2022 | Ken (kK kk@something.com) |
| ySite | Just SQL | //abc.com/a | 31/01/2022 | 21/05/2023 |  |

```
WITH cte_contentExpiry AS (       

    SELECT c.sitename
          ,c.pagetitle
          ,c.pageurl
          ,c.dateCreated
          ,c.expiryDate
          ,a.userid
    FROM dbo.content c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.assignments a
                 ON c.contentId     = a.contentId
    WHERE c.active   = 1

) SELECT   q.sitename
          ,q.pagetitle
          ,q.pageurl
          ,q.dateCreated
          ,q.expiryDate
        ,
        STUFF((SELECT '; ' + u.fName +  ' (' + u.userName + ' - ' + u.email + ')'
            FROM dbo.users u
            WHERE q.userId        = u.userId
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  AS reviewer
    FROM cte_contentExpiry q
GROUP BY   q.sitename
          ,q.pagetitle
          ,q.pageurl
          ,q.dateCreated
          ,q.expiryDate
          ,q.userId
```

Comment: FYI, `STUFF` isn't the "magic" here, it's `FOR XML PATH`'; all `STUFF` does is doing here is removing the first character from a delimited string.

Comment: As for the problem, you would be better off demonstrating what your data looks like *before* your attempt, not after it; it can be quite difficult for us to reverse engineer your data from the failed attempt. Are you also not on a version that supports `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: @david-l please indicate what is the SQL Server version?

Comment: You can determine your version of SQL Server by executing `SELECT @@VERSION`. `STRING_AGG` became available in SQL Server 2017 (14.0)

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your comments, sorry should have added the version. I've also added SQL fiddle with mock data to represent the raw I have

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @content TABLE 
(
    contentId int, 
    sitename varchar(20), 
    pageTitle varchar(30), 
    pageURL varchar(30), 
    dateCreated date,
    expiryDate date,
    active bit
);

DECLARE @assignments TABLE (userid int, contentId int);

DECLARE @users TABLE 
(
    userid int, 
    fname varchar(20), 
    userName varchar(30), 
    email varchar(30)
);
    
INSERT INTO @assignments (contentId,userid) VALUES
(1001,200),
(1001,201),
(1001,202),
(1002,203),
(1003,NULL);

INSERT INTO @users (userid,fname, userName, email) VALUES
(200,'James','jk','jk@something.com'),
(201,'David','dDel','dDel@something.com'),
(202,'Ali','aLee','aLee@something.com'),
(203,'Ken','Ken','kk@something.com');

INSERT INTO @content
(contentId,sitename, pageTitle, pageurl, dateCreated, expiryDate, active)
VALUES
(1001,'xSite','sql concat','//abc.com/fr','2023-02-02','2023-02-02',1),
(1002,'xSite','Join in SQL','//abc.com/vf','2020-02-20','2022/05/22',1),
(1003,'ySite','Just SQL','//abc.com/a','2022-01-31','2023-05-21',1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.sitename
        , c.pagetitle
        , c.pageurl
        , c.dateCreated
        , c.expiryDate
        , u.*
        --, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(u.fName,' (',u.userName,' - ',u.email,')'),'; ')
    FROM @content AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @assignments AS a
                    ON c.contentId = a.contentId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @users AS u ON a.userId = u.userId
    WHERE c.active = 1
)
SELECT sitename
    , pagetitle
    , pageurl
    , dateCreated
    , expiryDate
    , STUFF((SELECT '; ' + c.fName +  ' (' + c.userName + ' - ' + c.email + ')'
            FROM rs AS c
            WHERE p.sitename = c.sitename
             AND p.pagetitle = c.pagetitle
             AND p.pageurl = c.pageurl
             AND p.dateCreated = c.dateCreated
             AND p.expiryDate = c.expiryDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
            , 1, 2, '')  AS reviewer
FROM rs AS p
GROUP BY sitename
    , pagetitle
    , pageurl
    , dateCreated
    , expiryDate;
```

**Output**

| sitename | pagetitle | pageurl | dateCreated | expiryDate | reviewer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xSite | Join in SQL | //abc.com/vf | 2020-02-20 | 2022-05-22 | Ken (Ken - kk@something.com) |
| xSite | sql concat | //abc.com/fr | 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-02 | James (jk - jk@something.com); David (dDel - dDel@something.com); Ali (aLee - aLee@something.com) |
| ySite | Just SQL | //abc.com/a | 2022-01-31 | 2023-05-21 | NULL |

Comment: To avoid potential problems with certain special characters (like <, >, &, and others), a safer `... FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') ...` variation of the above can be used.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve.